# Simple JSON problem

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, galleria

I never worked with JSON and I really need to do it now, I've tried bunch of examples from jQuery page but it does not seem to work for me.

I have *.php file that is generating string, as I understand this is how I pass JSON to javascript from PHP. The string that I want to generate is very simple:

```
foreach ($imageList as $img)
{
    echo "{ thumb: 'media/img/t/$img', image: 'media/img/m/$img'},";
}
```

So the result would be something like (formatted)

```
{
thumb: 'media/img/t/123.jpg',
image: 'media/img/m/123.jpg'
},
{
thumb: 'media/img/t/1234.jpg',
image: 'media/img/m/1234.jpg'
},
```

and so on...

Somehow I think this is not the correct way of doing things, excuse me of course, but as I told I never worked with JSON format and I barely know what it even stands for.

I want this data to be located in javascript array so I can use it in my gallery like here (3. Using JSON) http://galleria.aino.se/docs/1.2/references/data/

Can someone help me with this one? I know that it is probably very easy problem, but for me as a total noob it is hard to understand. When I do know how to solve this I will probably understand how it works and how to use it, but now I really have no clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use [`json_encode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) as you have several issues in your created json object string.

```
<?php

$json_image_list = array();
foreach ($imageList as $img){
    $json_image_list[] = array(
        'thumb' => "media/img/t/$img",
        'image' => "media/img/m/$img",
    );
}

echo json_encode($json_image_list);

?>
```

So you know, here are a few problems in your [json](http://www.json.org/):

1. An array has to be in brackets ('[' & ']').
2. Your object properties must be wrapped in double quotes.

Also, see the bottom of [JSON.org](http://www.json.org/) for packages that are already written for the languages you'll be using on the web so you don't have to write your own.

Comment: Okey, this part seems to be done, but how do I recieve this data in to array inside JS? Using jQuery ofc..

Comment: You have to decode the string into a js object. You don't say how you are using jQuery, but if you are using the `$.ajax` function, set dataType to `"json"`. Or get json2.js from the link I gave in the answer.

Comment: Or try [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/). (I'm a little rusty on jQuery functions). And more: http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+ajax+tutorial+json

Comment: Thanks, got it to work, but now I face different problem tho )))

Answer (score 2):

The JSON is [invalid](http://jsonlint.com), don't write your own serializer, [perfectly good ones exist already](http://php.net/json_encode/).

Answer (score 1):

Don't build your own json. use `json_encode($some_php_data_structure)` to do it all for you. Otherwise you have to all the escaping/bracketing yourself, and at some point you'll miss something and end up with bad javascript, which will kill all of your client-side scripts.

All you have to do is build a data structure in PHP, pass it to [json_encode()](http://php.net/json_encode), and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way is to use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). It does all the work for you and translates PHP variables into JSON strings.

Answer (score 1):

The generated string is not valid JSON. All those objects should be in an array, and the name of the properties should be quoted. Why don't you use [json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)?

Answer (score 0):

You can populate a normal array in PHP, then do this to echo back the JSON:

```
echo json_encode($your_array);
```

Then you don't need to worry about the JSON syntax until you're parsing it.

Answer (score 0):

In response to the submitter's comment above:

> Okey, this part seems to be done, but how do I recieve this data in to array inside JS? Using jQuery ofc..

You can use jQuery's [`getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) function to receive JSON into a JavaScript array.